# Where in the Talmud does it say, if it indeed does, that one who’s thoughts are heard lives a life not worth living?

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash

In Chumash shiur in Yeshiva, I *think* I remember hearing that in the Gemara somewhere it says that “one who’s thoughts are heard lives a life not worth living”, or something like that. If it does say such a thing, where is it written?

Comment: I don’t understand the English rendition, can you elaborate?

Comment: @drshmuel it’s typically referred to in the realm of “psychiatry” as “thought broadcasting”, i.e that other people can hear your thoughts.